Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Carbon Gen 12 Fingerprint sensor (fprintd) keychain issues
So I have been using my ThinkPad a lot recently and I noticed that the Ubuntu fingerprint recorder in settings is terrible and does not work very well upon login (usually says failed to authenticate). So I found fprintd and enrolled my right-index-finger. This works very well but you need to have atleast 1 fingerprint enrolled under the Ubuntu recorder to enable fingerprint login. I have noticed that when I enroll my fingerprint it makes me login to my keychain everytime I login (previously I have disabled this by changing the password of my keychain to nothing). When I go to change the password back to nothing the system defaults to the Ubuntu fingerprint and does not work well. Is there anyway that I can either unlock my keychain automatically (I have tried updating the pam-auth files) or delete the password to my keychain without losing my fprintd functionality.

Try cleaning wherever you usually place your finger to login with your fingerprint.
